# Is this the Laurent series expansion of $f$ in $D?$

Tags: complex-analysis

> - Let a complex valued function $f$ be analytic on $D=\{z\in\mathbb C:R_1<|z-z_0|<R_2\}$ where $0<R_1,R_2<\infty.$ Moreover let in $D,~f$ can be represented as $$f(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n~(z\in D)$$Is this the Laurent series expansion of $f$ in $D?$

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is the Laurent series expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because a representation of the form $f(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$ is unique. And why is that? Because dividing both sides by $(z-z_0)^{m+1}$ and integrating over a circle $|z-z_0|=r$ with $R_1<r<R_2$, we obtain
$$\int_{|z-z_0|=r}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{m+1}}\,dz = 2\pi i a_m$$
Thus, every coefficient is determined by $f$.

(Technical remark: one has to know that the convergence is uniform on compact subsets of $D$. This follows from a standard comparison argument, as for Taylor series.)